# Ubuntu 17: Can't install mysqlclient

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, pip

Trying to follow a Django tutorial but I cannot install `mysqlclient`.

The tutorial claims that I can do so with the following command:

`pip install mysqlclient`

but this generates this error:

```
Collecting mysqlclient   Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-rrolctwh/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-rrolctwh/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-rrolctwh/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found


----------------------------------------  Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-rrolctwh/mysqlclient/
```

I have the most up-to-date pip and virtualenv installed.

I would like to be able to install `mysqlclient` so that I may continue with the tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

You should also install the mysql and python development headers and libraries:
https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python#prerequisites

Comment: I used the command provided on that website for python 3, but the terminal informed me that python3-dev is already the newest version. I tried to install mysqlclient anyway and got the same error again.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problems, but following the instructions in the [Official mysqlclient documentation](https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python#prerequisites) fixed it for me

but just to clarify I was running python 3.5 from a virtual environment
and after installing the prerequisites, it all worked fine

Answer (score 1):

The following solved it for me :

> You may need to install the Python 3 and MySQL development headers and libraries like so:

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential # Debian / Ubuntu

% sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel # Red Hat / CentOS
```

> Then you can install mysqlclient via pip now:

```sh
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

Source : https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient#prerequisites

Answer (score 0):

I had also similar issue on Centos 6, where there was a problem with mysql migration to maria, I had some conflicts, but finally I installed:

```
 yum list installed |grep MariaDB
MariaDB-client.x86_64  10.2.7-1.el6     @bull                                   
MariaDB-common.x86_64  10.2.7-1.el6     @bull                                   
MariaDB-compat.x86_64  10.2.7-1.el6     @bull                                   
MariaDB-devel.x86_64   10.2.7-1.el6     @bull                                   
MariaDB-server.x86_64  10.2.7-1.el6     @bull
```

And the issue was resolved.