# How to install Pip 3 and then Python Lib MySQLdb on Synology

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pip, synology

Im trying to install on Synology DS215j  the Python lib (**mysqlclient**) to connect Mysql

1) I install  Python 3.5 from the package manager **(OK)**

2) Then i SSh to Synology Station
and i get admin right -->  sudo -i

3) install Pip3
curl -k https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3 **(OK)**

I cheek what pakage are in the system
--> /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin/pip3 list
Package    Version

---

pip        19.1.1
setuptools 41.0.1
wheel      0.33.4

4) Then i try to install --> mysqlclient
--> /volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin/pip3 install mysqlclient

But i get this error Message.

ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
ERROR: /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/tmp/pip-install-kfd9_v0o/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 16, in  metadata, options = get_config()
File "/tmp/pip-install-kfd9_v0o/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 51, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-kfd9_v0o/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 29, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (_mysql_config_path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-kfd9_v0o/mysqlclient/

Unfortunately i have no idea how to fix this problem.
I will appreciate some help.
Thanks
marco

Comment: `Mysql` client need to be installed before attempting to install `mysqlclient` pip package. Can you try issuing `mysql --version` and share the output?

Comment: MySQL on a Synology? Do people use NAS as a general computer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 17: Can't install mysqlclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370385/ubuntu-17-cant-install-mysqlclient)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+OSError%3A+mysql_config+not+found

Answer (score 1):

I also could not install modules mysqlclient, mysql or mariadb... I'm sorry to suggest here only a workaround: installing "PyMySQL", a pure Python MySql client.
This way resolves some issues like lack of gcc on Synology NAS, missing pip dependencies, etc...
My solution/workaround:

```
/volume1/@appstore/py3k/usr/local/bin/pip3 install pymysql
```

For my usage, functions were the same so I just had to change the import:

```
>>> import pymysql  # import pure Python SQL client
>>> conn = pymysql.connect(database="usersdb", user="web", port=3307)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem.
At the beginning I thought that the issue on install mysqlclient was due to the fact that PIP had some problems. I was wrong. Pip Works well.

Mysqlclient just wont install on Synology.

I then try to install another Mysql Connector, i tried PyMySQL and it install easy an works fine.
Probably i was able to install PyMySQL because it (contains a pure-Python MySQL client library, based on PEP 249.)

https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/